# cannot read number of args

Tags: c, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm new to C. I want to simply print number of arguments provided via command line. I think the code could not be simpler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int arg_count, char * argv[])
{
printf("%c", arg_count);
};
```

I'm compiling this using following Makefile:

```
program_NAME := testprog
program_C_SRCS := $(wildcard ./src/*.c)
program_CXX_SRCS := $(wildcard ./src/*.cpp)
program_C_OBJS := ${program_C_SRCS:.c=.o}
program_CXX_OBJS := ${program_CXX_SRCS:.cpp=.o}
program_OBJS := $(program_C_OBJS) $(program_CXX_OBJS)
program_INCLUDE_DIRS := 
program_LIBRARY_DIRS :=
program_LIBRARIES :=

CPPFLAGS += $(foreach includedir,$(program_INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))
LDFLAGS += $(foreach librarydir,$(program_LIBRARY_DIRS),-L$(librarydir))
LDFLAGS += $(foreach library,$(program_LIBRARIES),-l$(library))

.PHONY: all clean distclean

all: $(program_NAME)

$(program_NAME): $(program_OBJS)
    $(LINK.cc) $(program_OBJS) -o $(program_NAME)

clean:
    @- $(RM) $(program_NAME)
    @- $(RM) $(program_OBJS)

distclean: clean

define OBJECT_DEPENDS_ON_CORRESPONDING_HEADER
    $(1) : ${1:.o=.h}
endef
```

Now when the code is compiled and run say:

```
./testprog 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

nothing gets returned. I really cannot see why this does not work since I can print individual arguments.
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`arg_count` is of integer type, use `%d` instead of `%c` while printing.

Check the `main()` prototype, `arg_count` is of `int` type.

```
int main(int arg_count, char * argv[]) { 
      printf("%d", arg_count);
      /*  code */
      return 0;
};
```

Always compile with enabled warning flag `-Wall` so that you should not spent more time on solving simple mistakes.

Comment: Also, it's strange if the compiler didn't give a warning. If it didn't then probably the OP is compiling without warnings enabled and that's something that you could point out.

Comment: yes @IharobAlAsimi I should have pointed out that. OP should compile with enable warning flag.